# User Defined Aggregate Functions Spark Java - merge problem

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to use a User Defined Aggregate Function following the documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-aggregate.html#untyped-user-defined-aggregate-functions), I want to first pass 2 values, x and y, to a [SimpleRegression](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/regression/SimpleRegression.html) then merge the simpleRegression by doing append. My problem is that the `reduce` function receives the values ​​correctly (if I ask it to print x and y it prints them correctly), however if I see how many values ​​have been added to the regressors in the `merge` function (using the `getN()` method as shown in the code provided) it returns me that no value has been added to those regressors, that is, as if no `addData()` was performed on them, why does this happen? What am I doing wrong?

Clearly this does not allow me to do what I want: to obtain the slope and the intercept of each regression line, because when the `finish` function is executed the regressors are empty and therefore slope and intercept are set to NaN.

This is my code (Java):

```
public static class RegressorAggregator extends Aggregator<Tuple2<Long, Long>, SimpleRegressionWrapper, LineParameters> {


    //Valore zero per l'aggregazione - dovrebbe soddisfare a+zero=a;
    public SimpleRegressionWrapper zero(){
        return new SimpleRegressionWrapper();
    }

    public SimpleRegressionWrapper reduce(SimpleRegressionWrapper simpleRegression, Tuple2<Long, Long> xy){
        double x = (double)xy._1;
        double y = (double)xy._2;
        simpleRegression.addData(x,y);
        return simpleRegression;
    }

    public SimpleRegressionWrapper merge(SimpleRegressionWrapper a, SimpleRegressionWrapper b){
        Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(getClass().getSimpleName());
        log.error(a.getN() + " " + b.getN());
        a.append(b);
        return a;
    }

    public LineParameters finish(SimpleRegressionWrapper simpleRegression){
        return new LineParameters(simpleRegression.getSlope(), simpleRegression.getIntercept());
    }

    public Encoder<SimpleRegressionWrapper> bufferEncoder(){
        return Encoders.bean(SimpleRegressionWrapper.class);
    }

    public Encoder<LineParameters> outputEncoder(){
        return Encoders.bean(LineParameters.class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be resolved changing this:

```
public Encoder<SimpleRegressionWrapper> bufferEncoder(){
        return Encoders.bean(SimpleRegressionWrapper.class);
    }
```

into this:

```
public Encoder<SimpleRegressionWrapper> bufferEncoder(){
        return Encoders.javaSerialization(SimpleRegressionWrapper.class);
    }
```